# Parse json array into list of struct golang

Tags: json, go, struct, unmarshalling

I have a json like below and I am trying to make a struct for below json which can store the data for me when I unmarshall it.

```
{
  "clientMetrics": [
    {
      "clientId": 951231,
      "customerData": {
        "Process": [
          "ABC"
        ],
        "Mat": [
          "KKK"
        ]
      },
      "legCustomer": [
        8773
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 1234,
      "legCustomer": [
        8789
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 3435,
      "otherIds": [
        4,
        32,
        19
      ],
      "legCustomer": [
        10005
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 9981,
      "catId": 8,
      "legCustomer": [
        13769
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 12124,
      "otherIds": [
        33,
        29
      ],
      "legCustomer": [
        12815
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 8712,
      "customerData": {
        "Process": [
          "College"
        ]
      },
      "legCustomer": [
        951
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 23214,
      "legCustomer": [
        12724,
        12727
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 119812,
      "catId": 8,
      "legCustomer": [
        14519
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 22315,
      "otherIds": [
        32
      ],
      "legCustomer": [
        12725,
        13993
      ]
    },
    {
      "clientId": 765121,
      "catId": 8,
      "legCustomer": [
        14523
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

`clientMetrics` is a json array which contains each `clientMetric` object. Each `clientMetric` object can have various fields into it. I tried something like below but I am confuse on how to add rest since I am coming from Java background and I don't see there is set available in golang. Also confuse on how to add `customerData` object too.

```
type ClientMetrics struct {
    ClientId    int64
    CatId       int64

  

}
```

What is the best way to `unmarshall` above json into a list of `ClientMetrics` struct in golang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json to go` here : https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

But it will repeat `CustomerData` struct twice make sure you should remove one of them.

I have created a sample struct for your scenario as follows :

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
        ClientMetrics []struct {
            ClientID     int `json:"clientId"`
            CustomerData struct {
                Process []string `json:"Process"`
                Mat     []string `json:"Mat"`
            } `json:"customerData,omitempty"`
            LegCustomer []int `json:"legCustomer"`
            OtherIds    []int `json:"otherIds,omitempty"`
            CatID       int   `json:"catId,omitempty"`
        } `json:"clientMetrics"`
    }
```

You can run it here in go playground  : https://go.dev/play/p/R1M1HfzpEny

Comment: How do I enforce uniqueness for all string and int array? I mean since there is no set datatype in golang so what can I do here?

Comment: You still around bro?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using VS Code, there are a few extensions that can do this job.
One of them is named [`Paste JSON as Code`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=quicktype.quicktype).

1. Install the extension
2. Copy the JSON and in your clipboard (ctrl+c)
3. Press Ctrl+Shift+P and select `Paste JSON as code`
4. Type name of struct and press enter

If this doesn't work for you, you can always use this site https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ but it would be a better practice to use the struct obtained after unselecting `Inline type definitions` option.

Comment: How do I enforce uniqueness for all string and int array? I mean since there is no set datatype in golang so what can I do here? –

Comment: I think what you're looking for here is an ENUM. Although, golang does not have support for that out of the box, you can achieve the same by using user defined types. https://go.dev/play/p/a1wMcpnha4q

And to enforce it in API requests, you can add custom checks in yourhandler/resource layer where you attempt to bind the JSON to struct

Comment: Aah.. Do you think you can provide an example so that I can understand better. As of now I am kinda confuse and I am not able to figure out on how can I use enum here to achieve this?

Comment: You around to help me out?